# Grouping Algorithm By Multiple Fields

Tags: algorithms

I'm looking for an algorithm that will group players from the same teams together throughout multiple matches.

In my case, every team has up to 4 players in every match.
Teams have subs, which means that it is not necessary that the same players will play in all the matches.
Each team has randomly assigned ID in form of UUID for each match, which means that the same team will not have the same ID throughout the matches.
My goal is to group row by team IDs and then group those groups by players that play in a team.

For this project, I'm using python with pandas library so if you don't know the name of such an algorithm any tips about how one might implement something like this with pandas will be much appreciated as well.

EDIT:
To be more specific I'm looking for such an algorithm (the name if exists). Also, adding the input and desired output of the algorithm for better understanding.

INPUT:

```
player_name    team_id   att1   attr2   ....
--------------------------------------------
A              1         1      2
B              1         3      5
C              1         9      7
D              1         1      2
E              2         3      5
F              2         9      7
G              2         1      2
H              2         3      5
I              3         9      7
J              3         1      2
K              3         3      5
L              3         9      7
M              4         3      5
N              4         9      7
O              4         3      5
P              4         9      7     <----- last entry for match 1
A              5         1      2
B              5         3      5
C              5         9      7
R              5         1      2     <----- sub
E              6         3      5
F              6         9      7
G              6         1      2
H              6         3      5
I              7         9      7
J              7         1      2
K              7         3      5
Q              7         9      7     <----- sub
Z              8         3      5     <----- sub
N              8         9      7
O              8         3      5
P              8         9      7     <----- last entry for match 2
```

OUTPUT:

````
Team 1
player_name    team_id   att1   attr2   ....
--------------------------------------------
E              2         3      5
F              2         9      7
G              2         1      2
H              2         3      5
A              5         1      2
B              5         3      5
C              5         9      7
R              5         1      2
--------------------------------------------

Team 2
player_name    team_id   att1   attr2   ....
--------------------------------------------
A              1         1      2
B              1         3      5
C              1         9      7
D              1         1      2
E              6         3      5
F              6         9      7
G              6         1      2
H              6         3      5
--------------------------------------------

Team 3
player_name    team_id   att1   attr2   ....
--------------------------------------------
I              3         9      7
J              3         1      2
K              3         3      5
L              3         9      7
I              7         9      7
J              7         1      2
K              7         3      5
Q              7         9      7
--------------------------------------------

Team 4
player_name    team_id   att1   attr2   ....
--------------------------------------------
M              4         3      5
N              4         9      7
O              4         3      5
P              4         9      7
Z              8         3      5
N              8         9      7
O              8         3      5
P              8         9      7
--------------------------------------------
```
````

Comment: Questions specific to particular programming languages of software libraries are off-topic here.

Comment: What's your question?  We're a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question for us to answer.  I don't understand what "group players from the same teams together" means.  Can you describe the inputs to the algorithm, and the desired output?  Are you looking for code or for an approach?  It sounds like you are asking for how to implement this, which would be off-topic here.

Comment: I would like to know the name of the algorithm if it exists.